# isAlive vs Join in JAVA Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Two ways exist to determine whether a thread has finished. First, you can call `isAlive()` on the thread. This method is defined by `Thread`, and its general form is shown here:

```
final boolean isAlive()
```

The `isAlive()` method returns true if the thread upon which it is called is still running. It returns false otherwise. While `isAlive()` is occasionally useful, the method that you will more commonly use to wait for a thread to finish is called `join()`

`isAlive()` vs `join()`. Advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While isAlive( ) is occasionally useful, the method that you will more
>   commonly use to wait for a thread to finish is called join( )

I don't understand. Why, according to you, `join()` is more commonly used than `isAlive()`? Do you have a proof for that?

They are two different methods defined for the Thread class:

[isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29):

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been
>   started and has not yet died.

[join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29):

> Waits for this thread to die.

One method performs a check, the other one waits for death of thread.

You'll use `isAlive()`, when you want to perfom a check about the life of a thread, without waiting, and it will return a boolean value about the status of thread.

You'll use `join()` if you want to wait for the death of thread. The meaning is that you want to wait for the completion of the task assigned to the thread.

Comment: From the comments, what I understood is that isAlive() and join() are no way related and should be used according to the need.

Comment: @Upen Yes, they're not related.

Answer (score 2):

> The isAlive() method returns true if the thread upon which it is called is still running.

That is not quite true - [public final boolean isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29)

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive **if it has been started** and has not yet died.

This means that you may get a `false` from `isAlive` if the thread **has not yet started** while 'join' will wait for it to start **and** finish before returning.

Comment: Also, what happens if the thread dies while the isAlive()) call is returning with 'true'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block until Thread is finished, then use join(). Otherwise - you decide.

If your logic does not block waiting for the thread then I think cleaner code look will be achieved with isAlive(). Just look at your code and see what looks nicer.

Comment: double negation spotted.

Comment: @UmNyobe, good point, thanks